# No entiendo por que me sale este error SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parametros, datos

tengo un problema con esta parte del código y no consigo entender por que no se parametrizan los datos de manera correcta.

### cuando realizo la consulta sin parámetro todo funciona de manera correcta.

```
$orden='asc';
$stmt=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Estado=1 ORDER BY Precio ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1,$orden);
$stmt->execute();
```

---

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''asc'' at

Comment: No estoy seguro que puedas enviar una palabra clave como parámetro... aunque, al estar enviando una cadena, tal vez puedas...

Comment: Intenta con esto, indicando el tipo. Tal como lo indica la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

`$orden='asc';`
`$stmt=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Estado=1 ORDER BY Precio :orden');`
`$stmt->bindParam(':orden', $orden, PDO::PARAM_STR);`
`$stmt->execute();`

Comment: Ya lo intente y nada.

Comment: pero será que el problema es por que intento enviar una palabra clave como parametro ?

Comment: Si la envías así? funciona? `$stmt=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Estado=1 ORDER BY Precio $orden?');`

Comment: No. si trabajo con Mysqli si funciona como dices pero en PDO no se pueden pasar las variables así en la consulta hay que parametrizar las variables

Comment: igual creo que no se pueden parametrizar palabras reservadas de sql en PDO ya que realice una prueba y también me dio error

Comment: Si, es probable que no se pueda. Aunque termine enviando una cadena al motor, da error. Acabo de probar y me permite parametrizar todo, menos palabras claves o reservadas.

Comment: Nada que un simple IF no pueda resolver... creas 2 sentencias, una asc, otra desc y validas el valor de $orden. No se si es lo ideal, pero en una consulta así pequeña no es un problema.

Comment: si así estoy haciendo no se si es lo mas ideal pero con eso se resuelve. muchas gracias por la ayuda !!!